# How do I debug this error with Python?

Tags: python, debugging

My code that I will post below gives me this error and I can't figure out why or how to fix it. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\j-a-c-o-b\newlc.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\j-a-c-o-b\newlc.py", line 76, in main
    for final_url in pool.imap(handle_listing, listings):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenpool.py", line 232, in next
    val = self.waiters.get().wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 166, in wait
    return self._exit_event.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\event.py", line 120, in wait
    current.throw(*self._exc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 192, in main
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\j-a-c-o-b\newlc.py", line 48, in handle_listing
    yellow_page = BeautifulSoup(download(yellow_page_url))
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1519, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1144, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1168, in _feed
    smartQuotesTo=self.smartQuotesTo, isHTML=isHTML)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._detectEncoding(markup, isHTML)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 1915, in _detectEncoding
    '^<\?.*encoding=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*\?>').match(xml_data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I don't know what it wants or what it means...

This is my code:

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import webbrowser
import time
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import os
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2
import urllib2
import urllib

def download(url):
    print "Downloading:", url
    s = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    if s[:2] == '\x1f\x8b':
        ifh = GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=StringIO(s))
        s = ifh.read()
    print "Downloaded: ", url
    return s


def replace_chars(text, replacements):
    return ''.join(replacements.get(x,x) for x in text)

def handle_listing(listing_url):
    listing_document = BeautifulSoup(download(listing_url))

    # ignore pages that link to yellowpages
    if not listing_document.find("a", href=re.compile(re.escape("http://www.yellowpages.com/") + ".*")):
        listing_title = listing_document.title.text
        # define an alphabet
        alfa = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        reps = {' ':'-', ',':'', '\'':'', '[':'', ']':'', '-Suite-' + alfa[1-26] : ''}
        if TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title) is not None:
            title, = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
            if ADDRESS_MATCH.match(listing_title) is not None:
                address, = ADDRESS_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
                yellow_page_url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/%s/%s?order=distance" % (
                    replace_chars(address, reps),
                    replace_chars(title, reps),
                )

                yellow_page = BeautifulSoup(download(yellow_page_url))

                page_url = yellow_page.find("h3", {"class" : "business-name fn org"})
                if page_url:
                    page_url = page_url.a["href"]

                    business_name = title[:title.index(",")]

                    page = BeautifulSoup(download(page_url))
                    yellow_page_address =  page.find("span", {"class" : "street-address"})
                    if yellow_page_address:

                        if SequenceMatcher(None, address, yellow_page_address.text).ratio() >= 0.5:
                            pid, = re.search(r'p(\d{5,20})\.jsp', listing_url).groups(0)
                            page_escaped = replace_chars(page_url, {':':'%3A', '/':'%2F', '?':'%3F', '=':'%3D'})

                            final_url = "http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&inPlaceID=%s&xxx_c_1_f_987=%s" % (
                                    pid, page_escaped)
                            return final_url


def main():

    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    listings_document = BeautifulSoup(download(START_URL))
    listings = listings_document.findAll("a", href = LOCATION_LISTING)
    listings = [listing['href'] for listing in listings]

    for final_url in pool.imap(handle_listing, listings):
        print final_url

        """
        if str(final_url) is not None:

            url = str(final_url)

            req = urllib2.Request(url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            page = response.read()
            time.sleep(2)

        """

for a in range(0,1):

    START_URL = 'http://www.locationary.com/place/en/US/Arkansas/Fayetteville-page2/?ACTION_TOKEN=NumericAction'
    TITLE_MATCH = re.compile(r'(.*) \(\d{1,10}.{1,100}\)$')
    ADDRESS_MATCH = re.compile(r'.{1,100}\((.*), .{4,14}, United States\)$')
    LOCATION_LISTING = re.compile(r'http://www\.locationary\.com/place/en/US/.{1,50}/.{1,50}/.{1,100}\.jsp')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Did you also get a `Failed to open` error message?

Comment: You *do* realize that your exception "handling" is choking the flow of your program, right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: why not expand upon that point as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very common mistake made by novices using any language that supports exceptions is that they catch exceptions that they *do not actually handle*. This leads to hard-to-debug errors since it disrupts the normal flow of the program.

Specifically, catching `urllib2.HTTPError` in `download()` is preventing *actual* problems from being propagated to the rest of the program. Either remove the exception handler altogether, or `raise` at the end of the handler to maintain flow.

Comment: In this case, the `download` function, when there's an error, returns `None` (the default for functions that don't reach a return statement). Then BeautifulSoup falls down on the None value, but the error doesn't reveal the real problem. As Ignacio says - don't catch errors somewhere where you can't do anything useful with them.

Comment: @jacob501 - When 2 out of 2 answers do not address your concern, you should: (1) Explain why they do not answer (2) Edit your question making it clearer.

Comment: @jacob501: Allow me to simplify then. **`download()` is failing, only you can't tell where or how because the exception handling is done incorrectly.**

Comment: @ThomasK But I thought that I put in the line of code "if blah blah is not None:" so I handled the None!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But why is the download() failing if I already handled the NoneType as I just said above ^^^

Comment: @jacob501: Really? In between the call to `download()` and the call to `BeautifulSoup()`? Because it's *very* well hidden...

Comment: @jacob501: You check after parsing the page that your regexes match. But there's no check that `download(listing_url)` has succeeded before you try to parse it. You could jam one in, or you could use exceptions *properly*.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now. People can be really impatient sometimes. I'm knew to programming and every question I've asked on here has gotten fairly impatient responses.

Comment: @jacob501: Well, you did say "this doesn't answer my question" when people were being helpful. While you're new, remember that more experienced coders might see better what the actual problem is, even if it doesn't seem like what you want. If you need more explanation, that's fine, but ask for it in terms of 'I don't understand foo', rather than 'your answer isn't useful'.